# Adding device-specific files as a codenameone native lib

Tags: android, codenameone

I want to add native code specific to a device to my native android libs.

So, in other words, I have a folder full of `*.so` files:
[image: SO File List]

I then have a seperate CN1Lib app with native code contianing several libs. The example app showes this folder being added alongside normal .jar libs, so I did the same with codenameone:
[image: native libs]

The `soFolder`containing all the `so` files (named correctly as per example android app).

I then build this CN1Lib, and add it to the main project under the lib folder, which works.
However, when I inspect the codenameone APK and compare it to the example android app, the .so files sit in different locations. The example app has it under a `lib` folder in its root, and the codenameone app has it under the `assets` folder. This causes the device that requires these files to not be able to find them.

[image: Example app vs Codenameone Structure]

The example app being on the left, and the codenameone app being on the right.

Is there any way to get the `so` folder under a `lib` folder in the apk file using codenameone?

Assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to go through the trouble of creating an AAR there is a semi-solution.

You could create a normal android library project, and after building it, manually open the archive and just drop the lib folder in there. You then add this jar file as a native android dependency.

When the build returns from codenameone, the folder should be sitting in the apk file :)

The correct way is most likely the AAR approach, but its not as straight-forward to do for a once-off solution.

Comment: I used this approach for now as it really is a build-once-and-forget situation. However, thanks to Shai for pointing out the more correct path to follow.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked on this much so I'm not a big expert here but as far as I understand you need to create an AAR file in Android Studio and use that. Based on the developer guide section [here](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html#_integrating_android_3rd_party_libraries_jni).